# I'm using react-slick, how can I export a React Component as a single element but remove the parent div on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component, react-slick

I have a slider I built in react js using react-slick

```
<Slider {...settings}>
   <FeatureSliderItems/>
 </Slider>
```

`<FeatureSliderItems/>` is defined below (It contains the slides to be displayed)

```
const FeatureSliderItems= () =>(
    <>
      <div className="slide-item">
         <h2 className="">Create multiple sub-account</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="slide-item">
         <h2 className="">Create multiple sub-account 2</h2>
      </div>
    </>
)
```

But the issue I have now is how I can make the `slide-items`  in `<FeaturedSliderItems/>` appear under `<Slider/>` as 2 sibling slides and not inside a single div (as exported in `<FeatureSliderItems/>` since I can only export my components under a single root element in react)

So basically I want this as my result

```
<Slider ref={c => (this.slider = c)} {...settings}>
    <div className="slide-item">
      <h2 className="">Create multiple sub-account</h2>
    </div>
    <div className="slide-item">
      <h2 className="">Create multiple sub-account</h2>
    </div>
 </Slider>
```

and not

```
<Slider ref={c => (this.slider = c)} {...settings}>
    <div>
      <div className="slide-item">
        <h2 className="">Create multiple sub-account</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="slide-item">
        <h2 className="">Create multiple sub-account</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
 </Slider>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You're already using a fragment so that's exactly what you should already be getting? If you inspect the DOM are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: My thought also but It doesn't seem to be working with react-slick, it's rendering all slider-items under a div.

Comment: It's possible that `react-slick` is adding the div internally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The children of Slider need to pass an array of elements. If you don't want to using `map` after `Slider` and only want use `FeatureSliderItems`. You can update `FeatureSliderItems` return an array of element. It is the same with using map.

```
const FeatureSliderItems = () => [
  <div className="slide-item">
    <h2 className="">Create multiple sub-account</h2>
  </div>,
  <div className="slide-item">
    <h2 className="">Create multiple sub-account 2</h2>
  </div>,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should create a component to render a single feature slide item. Then use that component for each item instead of a single component to render multiple. I just see repeated code in your example, and that tells me that a new component could be created.

```
<Slider {...settings}>
   {slideItems.map((item, index) => (
     <FeatureSliderItem key={index} item={item}/>
   )}   
 </Slider>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm aware I can do it this way also but I'm just trying to break up my code into the smallest possible unit.

Comment: This would result in the same number of components, and this component would be smaller that the `FeatureSliderItems` component you have in your example

Comment: Maybe, but the 'slide-item' contains more elements, I just minified for the sake of asking this question. That means I'd have to break each item of 'slides-item' into an array of objects in other to map it.